# Passing vector by reference and passing address of vector element

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, reference

I am new to c++. I am practicing vectors in cpp and wrote this program and it works fine. But the only concern for was in passing the vector as reference to `getdetails` and passing the address of vector element to a thread. Hope I am not doing anything wrong here.

```
struct studentDetails {
   char studentName[256];
   char studentAddress[256];
};

bool getdetails(int &numOfStudents, std::vector<studentDetails> &studentInfo)
{
   cout << "Enter the no of student"<<endl;
   cin >> numOfStudents;

   for (int i = 0; i < numOfStudents; i++)
   {
      studentDetails test;
      cout << "Enter the name" << endl;
      cin >> test.studentName;
      cout << "Enter the Address " <<endl;
      cin >> test.studentAddress;
      studentInfo.push_back(test);
   }
}

void* startThread(void *p)
{
   studentDetails *ptr = (studentDetails *) p;
   cout << "Name : "    << ptr->studentName << endl;
   cout << "Address : " << ptr->studentAddress << endl;
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<studentDetails> studentInfo;
   int numStudents;
   getdetails(numStudents, studentInfo);
   for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
   {
      cout << "Name : "    << studentInfo[i].studentName << endl;
      cout << "Address : " << studentInfo[i].studentAddress << endl;
   }

   pthread_t threadId[numStudents];

   for(int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
   {
      pthread_create(&threadId[i], NULL, &startThread, &studentInfo[i]);
   }
   for(int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
   {
      pthread_join(threadId[i], NULL);
   }
}
```

Comment: seems your code is missing a couple of lines (headers for example)

Comment: so what is the question in the end? what is wrong with the reference on vector? BTW why not using std::string in studentDetails?

Comment: You’re using pthread library in cpp, which will work fine but you might prefer using the cpp specific library. That way, you wouldn’t be forced to use a void pointer, which inhibits the possibility for the compiler to do type and const checking.

Comment: Be aware that, regardless of whether you're using pointers or references, once you get that pointer/reference, you're looking at that specific fixed location in memory. A vector will move all its data without warning if it needs to allocate more space (if you add more items than its current capacity), so your pointer will become useless (or worse, cause a crash) when that happens. In your example, you don't add anything after you get the pointer, so this is fine. But be aware that it can happen.

Comment: Pointers and references are *roughly* interchangeable. In most cases, there's no difference at all, except for getting rid of the need for `&`, `*` and `->`. References also can't be null. They can be a reference *to* a `NULL` value, but the reference itself must always point (refer) to something.

Comment: As far as passing a non-const reference to getdetails, that's absolutely fine - that's what you'd call an output parameter. However worth saying it makes more sense to return a vector. Also bear mind vector has a size() method which makes the int output parameter redundant.
However you're right to be concerned about passing a reference to a vector element to a new thread. For example, the vector could go out of scope and leave the pointer pointing to duff memory. I'd recommend looking at std thread in conjunction with a lambda. If I get time I'll post an example.

Comment: Also getdetails doesn't return anything, despite the function expecting a boolean return. Be sure to read the compiler warnings, they sometimes tell you you're doing something wrong - if you don't know what they mean, look them up!

Comment: @castro I assume vector may not go out scope until the main function exits. The main function exits only when all the threads join.

Comment: @Karthick that is true in this case and so for this example it's ok. It was more of a general point that passing a reference or a pointer into another thread and using it on that thread is inherently risky, and one needs to be careful when doing so (mainly ensuring the original object remains within scope for the lifetime of the thread and that the object is accessed in a thread-safe manner). Sometimes it is entirely appropriate (and indeed, necessary) to reference objects from more than one thread - but sometimes a copy of the data is more appropriate, so worth knowing how to do this.